# how do phones running newer Android versions behave with old built apps?

Tags: android, android-background

**For Example:**

Android [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/) from `WifiServiceImpl.java`

[image]

left is from Android v22 (Lollipop)**,** right is from Android v23 (Marshmallow)

**Question:** if I build an apk using compile/target sdk 22, and run my application on a phone running v23 and call the method `getScanResults()` which one of those two methods gets called?

***more info*:**
I have an app that manages WiFi, it does most of the work in the background, it  works perfectly on Lollipop and lower, but in Marshmallow, it only works if I have my application in the foreground, because `getScanResults()` returns an empty list if my app is in the background.

Comment: You're not packaging the Android OS with your application, so it has to use implementations already on the device. A v23 device will thus use the code on the right, even though you target the one on the left.

Comment: @Kevin thanks! is there something else that plays a part in this? because my app behaves differently if I build using sdk 23, then it always returns an empty list (doesn't matter if my app is in the foreground or background)

Comment: I'm not too sure about that. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295029/does-the-compile-sdk-affect-values-returned-by-android-functions) answer says Android can attempt to emulate older versions. it contradicts my previous comment, but I think it isn't the case here (more likely regards systems and themes, not implementations). Not sure why v23 breaks both fore and back ground for your app.